# Add decimal value to a date time in firemonkey delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Is there anyone who can help me with, for example:  Adding decimal 0,5 or 1 to a time?

eg. 0,5 + 15:30:50 = 16:00:50

Comment: What are your data types? Can you be precise about what you want to do.

Comment: The Input is written as a decimal value and is a string converted with StrToFloat and the time is in TdateTime. Why was the answer deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a time represented as a `TDateTime`, and wish to add a number of hours to it then you would do so like this:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.DateUtils;

function IncrementTimeBySpecifiedNumberOfHours(Time: TDateTime; 
  Hours: Double): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := TimeOf(Time + Hours/HoursPerDay);
end;
```

I'm assuming that you are concerned only with times here and wish to implement a 24 hour wrap-around. Hence the use of `TimeOf`.

Comment: I guess you've mistaken Time parameter with DateTime used in TimeOf